# Reliable sensing method for device inside a parcel to detect when/if the parcel is opened?

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, security

I'm wracking my brain for reliable ways for an electronic device to detect when/if the parcel it is sealed inside is opened.

The device will be sealed inside the package and activated via Bluetooth by the sender and then queried again by the receiver to confirm there was no tampering before taking delivery.

At this stage the enclosing parcel could be a box, envelope, or wrapping paper - the only restriction that it completely encloses the contents along with the sensor and possibly packaging material - but that may include further restrictions if I can't come up with an infallible detection method.

My first thought was a simple ambient light sensor - but the tamperer would just need to open the package in a darkroom.
Another thought is to actively pulse an illumination source and then average the amount reflected back from the inside of volume from multiple directions (to account for the device shifting inside the package).

Any strategies come to mind? I'm hoping this may already be a solved problem somewhere.

Comment: What's the point of it being opened in the dark room? If the person doing the tampering can't see anything they can't do anything? You can get light sensors that cover infra-red to ultra-violet, so even fancy lightly and cameras could be countered.

Comment: the package could be opened in the darkroom, sensor left there while the contents is taken out of the room and then the tamperer is free to do whatever.

Comment: how do you separate the sensor and the contents when you can't see either and they could be stuck together in some fashion?

Comment: How does a blind person read brail? It seems incomprehensible to me but they have zero trouble navigating by touch alone.

Comment: So the person tampering the package knows what to expect in there? They know what the device will be and how to remove it from rest of the package without setting it off?

Comment: "Infallible" is a pretty high bar. Are you assuming the attacker can intercept a parcel and analyze it completely before the next attack? Tamper-evident seals are a big business and don't require any electronics usually.

Comment: What if I just open the box and then tamper with your tamper-detection gadget so it always reports that no tamper occurred?

Comment: @Puffafish in theory they could have encountered the device on a previous attempt - bolloxed it up, but learned from there mistake on the next attempt.

Comment: @Spehro sorry I agree Infallible is overly optimistic but I would definitely like to be able to give a very solid probability. The hope is the product would have a broad market - so there could be multiple situations that they may wish to tamper with.

Comment: @Elliot way ahead of you on that one, got an anti spoofing algorithm planned out for that scenario

Comment: Seal the contents and your sensor in a bag purged with an inert gas.  Use an O2 sensor along with a light sensor to determine when the bag is opened.  Way overkill if you ask me, but if you're worried about darkrooms and infallibility it's an option.

Comment: @JohnD interesting - from memory O2 sensors would chew through battery since they need constant temp, but could use a CO2 sensor and pulse a hotwire coated with something to enrich the atmosphere once the parcel was sealed.

Comment: @norlesh I think there are some MEMS O2 sensors with reasonable power consumption that you could wake up and pulse periodically to check.  Alternately you could package your payload in a partial vacuum and use a pressure sensor to determine when it has been opened.

Comment: Or could place a desiccant inside the package and then monitor humidity

Comment: You should assume that your adversary knows how the tamper detection works...security by obscurity will not succeed. Also, assume that your adversary can detect when your device is operating, if it only wakes up periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a small 40 gague wire all around the package with a microprocessor on the inside and a way for the microprocessor to detect continuity of the wire. The microprocessor could log the time that the continuity was broken and you would know that the package has been opened. With a small wire one could also hide it between layers of packaging tape so no one would see it if they were opening the package.

One could also place the microprocessor on the inside of the package with contacts to the outside to make for easy installation. You cal also get microprocessors with encrypted firmware so it would be difficult to modify the time stamp.